Multiple branches in one window in multiple folder views
In vscode I want to open the main branch next to my test branch (like for example another folder view on the other side of the editor).

I need this so it's easier to copy the already made code (for example if I delete an old page and create a new one with the same name (so I can't just have the old page in the test repo and copy from there)).

i don't think its easily achieveable without a plugin, see this QA for some suggestions. if you want for a pure [tag:git] solution maybe git-worktree is useful, havent tried it myself though.

This problem can be solved by using git-worktree, which allows you to have multiple branches at the same time.
Assume that you are currently on the master branch at the root of your project. You can create an additional directory inside the project with the test branch using git worktree add test-branch test.
You will then be free to open ./colors.json from the master branch and ./test-branch/colors.json from the test branch, respectively, and copy-paste the data between those files
